# Angular 4 http get with query parameters

Tags: angular, http, query-string

The first block is working as expected

```
getQuotes(): Observable<Quote[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Now I am tring to add query params to this.url and the url have not changed

```
getQuotes2(): Observable<Quote[]> {
    let myParams  = new URLSearchParams();
    myParams.append('author', 'authorName');
    myParams.append('catid', '123');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ params: myParams });

    return this.http.get(this.url, options )
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

I have checked in devtools. Caching is switched off. I have tried { search: myParams }, with RequestOptions and return this.http.get(this.url, { params: myParams } )
Where I am not looking i see string concatination. These parameters are optinal and I append them on condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you imported params ?

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: I have checked, yes it works. The absent of import do not cause error messages.

Comment: @Eldar because there is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams ;)